# How to validate a JWT token from Auth0 in C#?

Tags: c#, jwt, auth0

I have an Auth0 access token coming from an SPA web application using their SDK using the PCKE workflow.

Auth0 provides limited examples in C# and I need to validate their tokens in an OWIN API as well as a console application.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working using the built in JwtSecurityTokenHandler configured to retrieve the certificate via 'http://auth.myApplication.com/.well-known/jwks.json' which is a custom domain configured in Auth0.  This solution works for the default 'issuer' domain that is created by Auth0 also.

OWIN Example:

```
public static class AppBuilderExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Use JWT Authentication.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">The <see cref="IAppBuilder"/> to use.</param>
    /// <param name="audiences">The expected audiences.  Will be validated in the token.</param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="IAppBuilder"/> instance.</returns>
    public static IAppBuilder UseJwtTokenAuthentication(
        this IAppBuilder app,
        params string[] audiences)
    {
        var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                                   {
                                       ValidateLifetime = true,
                                       ValidateAudience = true,
                                       ValidateIssuer = true,
                                       ValidateActor = true,
                                       ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                                       ValidAudiences = audiences,
                                       ValidIssuer = Constants.Issuer,
                                       IssuerSigningKeyResolver = Constants.GetSigningKey,
                                   };

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AllowedAudiences = audiences,
                TokenHandler = tokenHandler,
                TokenValidationParameters = validationParameters,
            });

        return app;
    }
}

public static class Constants
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The authentication issuer.
    /// </summary>
    public const string Issuer = "https://auth.myApplication.com/"; // custom domain for Auth0

    private static readonly OpenIdConnectKeyResolver KeyResolver;

    static Constants() { KeyResolver = new OpenIdConnectKeyResolver(Issuer, TimeSpan.FromHours(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="IssuerSigningKeyResolver" /> delegate to provide to <see cref="JwtSecurityTokenHandler" />.
    /// </summary>
    public static IssuerSigningKeyResolver GetSigningKey => KeyResolver.GetSigningKey;
}
```

Direct call Example:

```
        void ValidateToken(string authenticationToken)
        {
            var issuer = "https://auth.myApplication.com/"; // custom domain for Auth0
            var audiences = new[]
                            {
                                "https://secure.myApplication.com/",
                            };

            using (var signingKeyResolver = new OpenIdConnectKeyResolver(issuer, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
            {
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                                           {
                                               ValidateLifetime = true,
                                               ValidateAudience = true,
                                               ValidateIssuer = true,
                                               ValidateActor = true,
                                               ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                                               ValidAudiences = audiences,
                                               ValidIssuer = issuer,
                                               IssuerSigningKeyResolver = signingKeyResolver.GetSigningKey,
                                           };

                var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(authenticationToken, validationParameters, out var securityToken);

                if (principal == null || securityToken == null)
                {
                    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
                }
            }
        }
```

This requires a signing key resolver, the example is using the second option as that's what I needed:

It is baked into Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens (see example here: https://github.com/auth0/auth0-aspnet-owin/blob/master/src/Auth0.Owin.OpenIdConnectSigningKeyResolver/OpenIdConnectSigningKeyResolver.cs).

It is a little more work if using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt (see example here: https://github.com/NaosProject/Naos.Auth/blob/main/Naos.Auth.Recipes.Jwt/OpenIdConnectKeyResolver.cs) I wrote a piece of code to accomplish this which can be copied directly (MIT license) or installed as a mix-in using package 'Naos.Auth.Recipes.Jwt'.